# VMware ESXi dual / triple boot on a test machine

Tags: vmware-esxi, boot

Has anyone tried to setup a dual or triple boot (ESXi 5.5, Linux, Windows Server 2012R2) machine? This is for an app and controller card testing environment - at the moment we're dual-booting Linux/Windows and changing the startup disk through the server's boot menu for ESXi.

I'll give it a go myself if necessary, but if anyone else has tried and knows whether it's possible and/or there's any gotchas that would save some time and be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Q: Has anyone tried to setup a dual or triple boot (ESXi 5.5, Linux, Windows Server 2012R2) machine? A: Not in a production environment because that would be a ridiculous thing to do.

Comment: Also, why wouldn't it be possible? It's a "normal" OS in the end which you can dual, triple, or even octo-boot if you like. :)

Comment: @joeqwerty: agreed, that would be ridiculous in a production environment - but not in a testing environment, as I mentioned.

Comment: @Michelz: Have you tried it then? Any useful insight?

Comment: Why, in a test environment, would you not just put the Linux and Windows in VMs on the ESXi ?

Comment: @Iain: Because we are testing PCI Flash card drivers and caching/VSAN software for Windows, ESXi and Linux and they must be tested on the bare metal with the target OS - no abstraction layers or intermediate drivers must be in use. We also do testing in VMs.

Answer (score 4):

ESXi will run from a USB stick, that is probably the easiest way.  It won't be straightforward to dual boot just like an OS from the harddrive because it uses multiple partitions set up in a certain way, rather than a single booting partition.

Comment: Thanks James - yes, I am wondering about ESXi's multiple partition setup - hence my question. We already use USB sticks for ESXi on some servers, but it just shifts the issue to selecting another type of boot device in the BIOS setup or boot menu, which is what we want to avoid. Also, we want to stick to disk (magnetic or flash) media because taking images of the boot media for backups and restoring specific test environments is much quicker on HDD/SDD - I might try with a smaller stick, but writing back a 32GB USB drive from an cloned image took over an hour.

Answer (score 2):

It's been done with some success here: http://www.highlyunsupported.com/2012/03/multiboot-esxi-5-windows-2008-r2-rhel-6.html. Key to success is install ESXi first unless you are also installing Xen. Use Grub to chainload the ESXi SysLinux bootloader, that's the easiest path and the one I took. Alternatively if you are using a server with a built-in RAID controller you can use that to select what to boot.